# Use slider to choose which graph to show

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, slider

Suppose I want to show three simulations by reading three .xlsx files.
Next, I want to design a slider to choose which simulation to show.
If I move the slider to 0, then 0 will be the input to the function "update()". The first simulation will be shown.

The following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as wg

# input files

rm = pd.read_excel("test_3d.xlsx", header = None)
rm1 = pd.read_excel("test_3d1.xlsx", header = None)
rm2 = pd.read_excel("test_3d2.xlsx", header = None)
rec = np.shape(rm)
X = np.arange(1,rec[1]+1,1)
Y = np.arange(1,rec[0]+1,1)
x , y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


# Set 3D plots

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 0.8], projection = '3d')


# Choose which 3D plots to show

def update(val):
    if val == 0:
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)        
    elif val == 1:
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)
    elif val == 2:
        ax1.cla()
        ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)      
    
ax1.set_zlim(-110, -80)

# Design a slider to choose which simulation to show 

slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=2, description='this is slider')
slideroutput = wg.Output()
display(slider, slideroutput)


numberonslider = []
def on_value_change(change):

    with slideroutput:
        numberonslider.append(change['new'])
        print(numberonslider[-1])
    
    
ddd = slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
update(ddd)
```

If I move the slider, "ddd" gives you a list of 0, 1 or 2.

However, 3D-simulation does not show up. How to modify the code?

[image]

Comment: does your IDE allow you to have matplotlib animation? for example Jupyter requires either ``%matplotlib widget`` or ``%matplotlib inline`` import for this to work

Comment: @Karina Yes, I just modified my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using JupyterLab. I need `%matplotlib widget` for any kind of interactive matplotlib plot. The below code works fine, but won't work without `%matplotlib widget`.

warning: `%matplotlib widget` **is not the same as** `import matplotlib.widget`

You didn't provide any sample data, so I just made up some data. Basically the structure of your code was not correct, the `if` part should be inside the `def on_value_change(change):`. See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import ipywidgets as wg
%matplotlib widget

X = np.arange(5)
Y = np.arange(5)
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
rm = np.sin(x)
rm1 = np.cos(x)
rm2 = y

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 0.8], projection = '3d')

# Design a slider to choose which simulation to show 
slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=2, description='this is slider')
slideroutput = wg.Output()
display(slider, slideroutput)

ax1.cla()
plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)

numberonslider = []
def on_value_change(change):
    with slideroutput:
        numberonslider.append(change['new'])
        if numberonslider[-1] == 0:
            ax1.cla()
            plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
            ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
        elif numberonslider[-1] == 1:
            ax1.cla()
            plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
            ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
        elif numberonslider[-1] == 2:
            ax1.cla()
            plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
            ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
    
slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

Output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

ask again if my explanation is somehow unclear.

Comment: Thanks! I just ran your code; however, it does not show any graph but with the following (I use JupyterLab)      "
Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
IntSlider(value=1, description='this is slider', max=2)
Output()".                        How to fix that?   Thanks again!

Comment: Can you try to plot any graph and take a screenshot of it and post it in your question? I just want to see if the matplotlib interactive installation is complete (it must have the side menu like my screenshot). Just plot any random graph, ``plt.scatter(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))`` would be enough. I kind of have an idea why it won't work in your JupyterLab but I just want to be sure first before giving you any further instructions.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. But it looks like it does not have to be in the JupyterLab environment; Jupyter Notebook works.!

Comment: And the problem was? matplotlib widget? Yes, basically what works for JupyterLab will also work for Jupyter Notebook (mostly).

Comment: Not sure the problem was. I guess the problem might come from I just installed file related to %matplotlib widget at that moment. Now, it works after reopening the computer.