# (Python & Tkinter) How to add a slider on a graph to choose a graph to show

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, slider

Please refer to the two questions I have asked before if necessary:

1. [Use slider to choose which graph to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730880/use-slider-to-choose-which-graph-to-show)
2. [(Python) Use Tkinter to show a plot in an independent window (Jupyter notebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391176/python-use-tkinter-to-show-a-plot-in-an-independent-window-jupyter-notebook)

Now, my question is the extension of 2., "how to add a slider to the independent window for the plot".

My codes:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from IPython.display import clear_output
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import ipywidgets as wg
import os
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = Tk()
root.title('An Easy Example')
root.geometry("800x800")

new_width = 150
new_height = 150

def plot_choose_fig():
    X = np.arange(5)
    Y = np.arange(5)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    rm = np.sin(x)
    rm1 = np.cos(x)
    rm2 = y
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 0.8], projection = '3d')
    # Design a slider to choose which simulation to show 
    slider = wg.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=2, description='this is slider')
    slideroutput = wg.Output()
    display(slider, slideroutput)
    ax1.cla()
    plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
    ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
    numberonslider = []
    def on_value_change(change):
        with slideroutput:
            numberonslider.append(change['new'])
            if numberonslider[-1] == 0:
                ax1.cla()
                plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
                ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
            elif numberonslider[-1] == 1:
                ax1.cla()
                plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
                ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm1, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)
            elif numberonslider[-1] == 2:
                ax1.cla()
                plt.title(f"This is slider number {str(slider.value)}")
                ax1.plot_surface(x, y, rm2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 10, antialiased = False)    
    slider.observe(on_value_change, names='value')

plt.show()

# Window

resultButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'show', command = plot_choose_fig)
resultButton.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=15, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

In this code, when I push 'show' button on the window, I "hope" it will pops out the following plot **with a slider on it to choose which graph to show** as I asked before (see the link above).

[image]

However, there is no slider on it. The slider on the Jupyter notebook cannot control the plot.
How to fix it?  Thanks a lot

Comment: first put code with correct indentations.

Comment: in your code I see one big mess - mixed three different GUIs - IPython, tkinter and matplot window. If you want to use `tkinter` then you would have to use special function to embed plot in tkinter window. But matplotlib has own window with own tollbar at the bottom and you can add own buttons to this toolbar.

Comment: example which shows how to add toggle button to toolbar [Tool Manager — Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/toolmanager_sgskip.html)

Comment: @furas Sorry about that. I fixed the indentations. If you pick the codes in the function "plot_choose_fig()" out and run it, you can get the plot with a slider. However, if you embed the codes in the 'tkinter' environment, there is no slider on the plot. I have trouble on this.